# How to handle POST results with formidable package and mongoose?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongoose, formidable

I did some research on handling POST request with node.js, so that's working now, kind of.
I also know how to save a new JSON object to a mongoDB collection with mongoose.
I feel like I'm close to the solution but I'm having trouble finding the answer.

#### The specific problem

Now, I need some help to put these two together.

Handling POST request [ok+-] => *converting to JSON object/mongoose object* [not okay] => saving it to collection [ok+-]

#### The controllers code

Here is the code I'm using. The basic features work :

- handling the fields posted and "saving" them to an object
- rendering the fields posted (the "fields" object)

**The code:**

```
// controller function for adding a ressource
var post = function(req, res){
  // incoming form
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  var fields = {};

  console.dir('ceci est bien un post');
  // everytime an field is parsed...
  // This is the place where I should do validation and throw errors if needed
  form.on('field', function (field, value) {
      console.log(field);
      console.log(value);
      fields[field] = value;
  });


  // Once the form is parsed completely
  form.on('end', function () {
      // testing the output
      var ressources = util.inspect(fields, {showHidden: false, depth: null});
      console.dir(util.inspect(fields, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));

      // here save it in mongodb collection
      var ressource = new Ressource(fields);

      // ressource.save(function (err, ressource, isSuccess) {
      //       if (err) {
      //         res.status(400);
      //         res.send('Error occured ' + err);
      //       }
      //       else if (isSuccess === 1) {
      //         res.status(201);
      //         res.send(ressource);
      //       } 
      //       else {
      //         res.status(400);
      //       }
      //     });

      // rendering the page with the results
      res.render('addRessourceView', {
                  title: 'Ressources',
                  fields: ressources
              });
  });

  form.parse(req);
};
```

And here's the mongoose model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ressourceModel = new Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  descr_short: { type: String },
  m_visual: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  m_writing:{ type: Boolean, default: false },
  m_moving: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  m_speaking:{ type: Boolean, default: false },
  m_music:{ type: Boolean, default: false },
  age: String,
  minAge: { type: Number }, 
  maxAge: { type: Number }, 
  prerequisite:{ type: Array,
            items: { type: String },
            uniqueItems:  true},
  language: { type: String },
  source: { type: String },
  intra_identify: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  intra_expression: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  intra_comprehension: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  intra_regulation: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  intra_utilisation: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  theme_impulsivity: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  theme_violence: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  inter_identify: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  inter_expression: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  inter_comprehension: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  inter_regulation: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  inter_utilisation: { type: Boolean, default: false },
  details:{ 
    type: Object,
    properties: {
      goals: {  type: Array,
                items: { type: String },
                uniqueItems:  true},
      preparation: String,
      exercices: {  type: Array,
                    items: { type: Object }},
      reflexion: String
    }
  },
  upload:{  type: Array,
          items: { type: Object }}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ressource', ressourceModel);
```

*Note : evrything that is "boolean" is a checkbox input*

So all these fields are also in the form (I've just not implemented the file upload).
So basically what I need help for is:

- adapting the post fields into something I can use with mongoose and save it
- maybe some help on how add some validation (like being sure the minAge is smaller than maxAge, or other stuff)
- and if you have time or would want to, how to handle file uploads

I'm really here to learn, I'm just a beginner and I tried to be as clear as possible with my question, and I hope you guys will be able to help me out!

Thanks,
Xogno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesterday, I spent the whole day working on it and I came to make it work as I wanted ! Actually, after researching a bit more, it wasn't really difficult : it just needed some good logic and taking the time to do it.

***Disclaimer*** : I'm using 'formidable' package to handle the post request, and learned using it with [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-and-handling-forms-in-node-js/).

I first started by adding the structure with comments, just to write down the logical thinking behind my code. And then I started to implement the code for each field one by one. `form.on('field'....){}` executes each time a field is parsed, so that's how I cand handle them one by one. To do that i used a `switch(true)` with multiples `cases ... : ... break;` .
I added the verification needed, adding an error to the object, and this way all the fields were added one by one to an JSON object.

Regarding errors, I displayed them using EJS template in the html page.

Then, once everything was working (handling POST fields and handling errors), the only thing I had left to do was linking it (saving it) to the mongodb collection, using `.save` method from mongoose.

So this happens all on server side, and doesn't happen dynamically. Maybe later I will recode it to work dynamically, with ajax or some other framework (Vue.js ?), so it doesn't need to reload the whole page and will be more efficient.

Here's the code in case it might help some!

---

### The code handling the post request

#### form.on('field') // handling each field one by one

```
form.on('field', function (field, value) {
        console.log(field);
        console.log(value);



        switch (true) {
            //check if title is not empty, if empty, throw error
            case field === 'title':
                if(value == ''){
                        // then error
                        console.log('titre vide')
                        fields.error = ['title-empty'];
                        fields[field] = value;
                    }
                    else{
                        fields.error = [];
                        fields[field] = value;
                    }
                break;
            // check if description is not empty
            case field === 'short_descr':
                if(value == ''){
                        // then error
                        console.log('titre vide')
                        fields.error = ['descr-empty'];
                        fields[field] = value;
                    }
                    else{
                        fields[field] = value;
                    }
                break;
            // when receiving minAge or maxAge, save it as number
            case (field === 'minAge' || field === 'maxAge') :
                if(field === 'maxAge'){
                    var maxAge = value;
                    if(Number(maxAge) < Number(fields.minAge)){
                        // then error
                        console.log('Error :  maxAge plus petit que minAge')
                        fields.error.push('maxAge<minAge');
                    }
                }
                fields[field] = Number(value);
                break;
            // if 'objectives'
            case field === 'objectives':
                console.log('hey we have an objectif!')
                // when receiving an objective, verify if there's already one
                if('objectives' in fields.details){
                    //then there is already an objective object
                    console.log('adding an objective to the list');
                    fields.details[field].push(value);
                } 
                // then we create the objective entry in fields.details
                else {

                    fields.details[field] = [value];
                    console.log('ajouté aux détails');
                }

                break;
            // if 'materials'
            case field === 'materials':
                console.log('hey we have an material!')
                // when receiving an objective, verify if there's already one
                if('materials' in fields.details){
                    //then there is already an objective object
                    console.log('adding an material to the list');
                    fields.details[field].push(value);
                } 
                // then we create the objective entry in fields.details
                else {

                    fields.details[field] = [value];
                    console.log('ajouté aux détails');
                }

                break;
            // when receiving an exercice, verify if there's already an exercice that exists
            // if there's already an exercice that exists, and this one isn't null, add this one as another exercice
            // verify also if ex_time is a number
            // and insert it under 'details.exercices' (array of objects : {ex_descr: '', ex_time:''})
            // renvoyer une erreur si le temps est vide ou si pas un nombre
            case field === 'exercices':
                console.log('hey we have an exercice!')
                // when receiving an objective, verify if there's already one
                //first check if it's not empty

                if('exercices' in fields.details){
                    if(value === ''){
                        //it's empty, add an error
                        fields.error.push('Empty-' + field + '[' + j + ']');
                        console.log('exercice is empty');
                    }

                    //then there is already an objective object
                    console.log('adding an exercice to the list');
                    var object_exercices = {};
                    object_exercices.ex = value;
                    fields.details.exercices.push(object_exercices);
                    j++;

                } 
                // then we create the objective entry in fields.details
                else {
                    if(value === ''){
                        //it's empty, add an error
                        fields.error.push('Empty-' + field + '[' + j + ']');
                        console.log('exercice is empty');
                    }

                    var object_exercices = {};
                    object_exercices.ex = value;
                    fields.details.exercices = [object_exercices];
                    console.log('ajouté aux détails');
                    j++;
                }

                break;

            //if it's an exercice_time we need to add it to the exercice object in the exercice array
            case field === 'exercices-time':
                console.log('hey we have an exercice-time!')
                // when receiving an exercice-time, verify if there's already an exercice existing
                if ('exercices' in fields.details){
                    if(isNaN(value) || value === ''){
                        // if it's not a number, push a new error
                        fields.error.push('NaNexercice_time[' + i + ']');
                        console.log('but its not a number or is empty ' + i);

                        //recuparate the object of the exercice
                        var object_exercices = {};
                        object_exercices = fields.details.exercices[i];
                        object_exercices.exercice_time = value;
                        // add the value of ex_time to it
                        fields.details.exercices[i] = object_exercices;
                        i++;
                    } else {
                    // if it's a number
                    // and then there is already an exercice object
                    console.log('adding an exercice-time to the last exercice ' + i);

                    //recuparate the object of the exercice
                    var object_exercices = {};
                    object_exercices = fields.details.exercices[i];
                    object_exercices.exercice_time = Number(value);
                    // add the value of ex_time to it
                    fields.details.exercices[i] = object_exercices;
                    i++;
                    }
                }

                break;

            // if "preparation" add it to details.preparation
            case field === 'preparation':

                fields.details[field] = value;
                console.log('ajouté aux détails');
                break;

            case field === 'intra_identification' || field === 'intra_regulation' || field === 'intra_understanding' 
                || field === 'intra_utilisation' || field === 'intra_expression' || field === 'inter_identification' 
                || field === 'inter_expression' || field === 'inter_utilisation' || field === 'inter_regulation' 
                || field === 'inter_understanding':

                //to see if they've at least checked one competence
                fields[field] = value;

                break;

            // otherwise it's a basic input
            default:
                fields[field] = value;
        }
    });
```

#### form.on('end') // once the whole form is parsed

```
// Once the form is parsed completely
    form.on('end', function () {
        // last error handling

        //test if they've at least added one competence
        if(!fields.intra_identification && !fields.intra_regulation 
        && !fields.intra_understanding && !fields.intra_utilisation 
        && !fields.intra_expression && !fields.inter_identification 
        && !fields.inter_expression && !fields.inter_utilisation 
        && !fields.inter_regulation && !fields.inter_understanding) {
            fields.error.push('No competence selected');
                            console.log('No competence selected');
        }

        // testing the output
            console.dir(util.inspect(fields, {showHidden: false, depth: null}));

        //time to save
        // see if there were errors
        if(fields.error.length < 1){
            //no errors
            //then save it in the database
            console.log('no errors');

            // save it in mongodb collection
            var ressource = new Ressource(fields);

            ressource.save(function (err, ressource, isSuccess) {
                  if (err) {
                    res.status(400);
                    //res.send('Error occured ' + err);
                    res.render('addRessourceView', {
                                title: 'Ressources',
                                fields: fields,
                                saved: false
                            });
                  }
                  else if (isSuccess === 1) {
                    res.status(201);
                    //res.send(ressource);
                        // render the page with save success
                        res.render('addRessourceView', {
                                title: 'Ressources',
                                fields: fields,
                                saved: true
                            });
                  } 
                  else {
                    res.status(400);
                    res.render('addRessourceView', {
                                title: 'Ressources',
                                fields: fields,
                                saved: false
                            });
                  }
                });


        } else {
            console.dir(fields.error);

            // render the page with save success
            res.render('addRessourceView', {
                    title: 'Ressources',
                    fields: fields,
                    saved: false
                });
        }


    });
    form.parse(req);
```